# SQL Tables need to be appended, but not like JOINS

Tags: sql, sql-server-2008

I've a scenario as below.
I've two tables, and a Common column/Key between the two.
I need Table2 data to be just appended to Table1 without repetition like JOINs.
If there are more rows in one table, other table rows can be NULL.
As shown in figure, Result Table has NULLs when there is no corresponding row count from Table2.

[image: Two Tables Need to be appended]

I tried using Joins, but I'm getting a result of 45 rows. But I should get 9 rows.

Thanks in advance.

Edit: Added my queries

```
SELECT DISTINCT
 APPT.PRSN_ID
,APPT.SCHEDULEDAPPOINTMENTS 
,APPT.OVERDUEAPPOINTMENTS           
,Visit.ENCOUNTER_CATEGORY 
,Visit.ENCOUNTER_TYPE 
,Visit.ENCOUNTER_DATE 
,Visit.ENCOUNTER_FOLLOWUP_DATE 
FROM 
APPOINTMENTS APPT   
OUTER APPLY dbo.fn_GetVisitsOfAPerson(PROV.PRSN_ID) AS Visit

/***********************************************************/
--IN THE ABOVE QUERY, THE FUNCTION IS DEFINED AS BELOW

CREATE FUNCTION dbo.fn_GetVisitsOfAPerson(@PrsnID AS bigint)  
RETURNS TABLE 
AS 
RETURN 
   ( 
        SELECT                      
            VISITS.PVISITS_PRSN_KEY 
            ,DATA.HE_Category_Description  AS 'ENCOUNTER_CATEGORY'
            ,DATA.HE_Type_Description AS 'ENCOUNTER_TYPE'
            ,VISITS.PVISITS_DATE  AS 'ENCOUNTER_DATE'
            ,VISITS.PVISITS_FOLLOWUP_DATE  AS 'ENCOUNTER_FOLLOWUP_DATE'                                         
        FROM
            [HS_PRSN_HEALTH_VISITS] VISITS INNER JOIN 
            [HS_HealthEncounter_Table] DATA ON 
            ENCOUNTER.PVISITS_CATEGORY = DATA.HE_Category_Code AND 
            ENCOUNTER.PVISITS_TYPE = DATA.HE_Type_Code 
        WHERE   
            PVISITS_PRSN_KEY = @PrsnID          
            AND PVISITS_VOID = 0 
    ) 
GO
```

Comment: Can you please post your your sql statement that does not work?

Comment: http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/285551/why-may-i-not-upload-images-of-code-on-so-when-asking-a-question/285557#285557

Comment: The problem is you haven't defined the join, so you get each of the 9 rows from one joined to each of the 5 rows in the other. Your sample shows no field that could be used between the two tables.

Answer (score 0):

I cannot read your data tables, but I think you just need to introduce a row number.

It would be something like this:

```
select . . .
from (select t1.*, row_number() over (partition by key order by ??) as seqnum
      from table1 t1
     ) full join
     (select t2.*, row_number() over (partition by key order by ??) as seqnum
      from table1 t2
     ) t2
     on t1.key = t2.key and t1.seqnum = t2.seqnum;
```

Answer (score 0):

Based on you wanting the 9 rows present in the Visit table it looks like you need an OUTER JOIN, something like:

```
SELECT DISTINCT
 APPT.PRSN_ID
,APPT.SCHEDULEDAPPOINTMENTS 
,APPT.OVERDUEAPPOINTMENTS           
,Visit.ENCOUNTER_CATEGORY 
,Visit.ENCOUNTER_TYPE 
,Visit.ENCOUNTER_DATE 
,Visit.ENCOUNTER_FOLLOWUP_DATE 
FROM Visit
LEFT OUTER JOIN
APPOINTMENTS APPT   
    ON Visit.key = APP.key
```